# Optparse with integer argument

Tags: python, optparse

I hit the following interesting error:

```
parser.add_option("-n", "--number", metavar="NUMBER", type="int", 
                  help="number is NUMBER")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

if options.number: # User added a number
  do something
  exit(0)
```

After a while I found out that my application does not work if the number is `0` but this should be valid number (it should be >= 0). The problem is that `0` is `False`.

should I change it to:

```
if options.number is not None:
```

or something more sophisticated?

Comment: @MarceloCantos Yes, I'm asking because the app could look unprofessional.

Comment: I kept a print-out from an old job for posterity. It takes a few hundred lines over several functions (not to mention two or three workflow diagrams) to compare two dates and raise an error if one precedes the other. The notion of "unprofessional" (or "sophisticated") should never come into it. Use the simplest thing that works, period. Note that I'm not criticising the question; it's a reasonable question to ask. But when someone else worries that their code isn't sophisticated enough, I get nervous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, integers can be used as boolean values, whereas anything non-zero is resolved to `True` and `0` to `False`. So if you want to check if the option `--number` is set, you have to check against `None` (which would mean, that the option is not set).

So:

```
if options.number is not None:
```

is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Also, consider using the argparse module instead of optparse, as the latter is deprecated since Python 2.7. The last section of the argparse documentation is about upgrading optparse code:

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

I don't know how it deals with your particular problem though.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have appetite to read a long webpage with argparse, but the section about upgrading seems to speed up the switch between argparse and optparse.